# Upload videos to multiple channels via Youtube API v3

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to upload videos to multiple channels via the Youtube Data API v3.

I can do it properly when uploading videos to the main default channel, however I can't when we try to upload them into a different channel which is part of the same Youtube account (so the `OAuth2` credentials should be valid).

According to the docs, I've to pass to the API the following params: `onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel` and `onBehalfOfContentOwner` when calling the endpoint: `/youtube/v3/video/insert`

The point is we don't have a clear idea about what is the `onBehalfOfContentOwner` value is. Is it the main email address associated to the owner? How we can obtain it? Is it required or not?
Isn't enough passing only the target channel ID when uploading?

By the other hand, I created multiple channels from the Youtube CMS for partners, but I'm not able to retrieve them when calling the API via: `youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&mine=true`

I can only see one unique channel (the main one).

Answer (score 0):

You provide your CMS auth credentials in `onBehalfOfContentOwner`, which can only be used in a properly authorized request.

Note that since you've created channels for different partners, the request must be authorized using the **CMS account** that is linked to the content owner specified in`onBehalfOfContentOwner`. Lastly, the channel that the `onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel` parameter value specifies must be linked to the content owner that the `onBehalfOfContentOwner` (YouTube channel ID of the channel to which a video is being added)  parameter specifies.

If you are using Google+ to manage all those accounts, read [here](http://youtube-eng.blogspot.com/2013/06/google-page-identities-and-youtube-api_24.html) for more information. If you are a content owner who manages all of the channels, you can use the Content ID API.

Answer (score 0):

The CMS account is not necessary here (since a user who has multiple youtube channels associated with a single google account, may not necessarily have a CMS account, e.g., I dont have one).

Prior to creating the API client, we need to obtain the credentials using `oauth2 flow` authentication, which requires the `client_secrets_file` (json downloaded for the client app created on google cloud), as done in the following code snippet with `google-api-python-client`.

```
scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload"]
credentials = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
              client_secrets_file, scopes).run_console()
```

Now, as part of the authentication procedure,

- the user is first asked to choose the google account and
- then the user is prompted to choose the brand account (the youtube channel), when he has multiple youtube channels that use the same google account, as shown below:

[image]

Once the authentication is successful, the user will be able to upload videos to the selected channel only using the API client (`YoutubeDataAPIClient`) created. The following `python` code snippet shows how the youtube v3 data API (`insert`) can be used to upload a test video (to the selected channel).

```
youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build("youtube", "v3", credentials=credentials) 
request = youtube.videos().insert(
    part="snippet,status",
    body={
      "snippet": {
        "description": "A test video",
        "title": "test video",
      },
      "status": {
        "privacyStatus": "public"
      }
    },        
    media_body=MediaFileUpload('test_video.mp4') # path to the test video to be uploaded
)
response = request.execute()
```